# make a movieclip move on motion path

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am making a snake and ladder game for my project.

My game is almost done except that now i need to make the game piece follow a "motion path" to go up the ladder "smoothly" instead of straight jumping to the tile that the ladder ends at.

I have been searching on how to make a movie clip move on motion path. But none of them are useful to me as i only need the game piece to move along the motion path when it reaches a special tile(eg. ladder or snake).

So my question is how do i exactly code my game such that when the game piece reach a special tile, it "snaps" onto the motion path and move accordingly to the path?

Here's my current code that i used to move my game piece up the ladder :

```
if(playerTile[i] == startLadder1 ){
    ladder4.play();
    playerTile[i] = destLadder1;        
    players2[i].x = tiles[playerTile[i]].x + offsets[i].x;
    players2[i].y = tiles[playerTile[i]].y + offsets[i].y;

}
```

playerTile is the current tile that the game piece is on.
startLadder1 is the tile at the start of a ladder.
destLadder1 will be the end of a ladder.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400642/attaching-movieclip-along-a-path-with-rotation-through-as3/9403446#9403446

Answer (score 0):

Use a Tweening engine, such as Tweensy or [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). For example, Tweensy's [Bezier2D](http://docs.flashdynamix.com/tweensy/original/com/flashdynamix/motion/guides/Bezier2D.html) would probably give you the curve you wanted.